# Double Sorting SQL results with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting

I'm using a LEFT JOIN to get top ranking post (ranks are in one table, post information in another) to get the top 4 ranked post published in the last two weeks. The way I've been able to get this information was just sorting by the top rank. However, I want my top 4 results to not appear in order of their ranking (voting.vote), but in order of their published date (entries.id). I'm not sure what the best way of doing this would be. Below is my SQL statement that currently works to display the top 4 ranked items in the timeframe.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT entries.permalink, entries.title, voting.vote FROM entries LEFT JOIN voting ON voting.id = entries.id WHERE date>='$twoweeks' ORDER BY voting.vote DESC LIMIT 4");
```

Is there a way I can get the 4 row result to then be ordered by the entries.id or do I need to just do this externally in php with arrays and such?

BELOW EDIT IS SOLUTION FROM INFO PULLED FROM COMMENTS.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT 
  entries.permalink, 
  entries.title, 
  voting.vote,
  entries.id
FROM entries 
LEFT JOIN voting ON voting.id = entries.id 
WHERE date>='$twoweeks' 
ORDER BY voting.vote DESC 
LIMIT 4
) t
ORDER BY id;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, I want my top 4 results to not appear in order of their
>   ranking (voting.vote), but in order of their published date
>   (entries.id).

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT 
      entries.permalink, 
      entries.title, 
      voting.vote 
    FROM entries 
    LEFT JOIN voting ON voting.id = entries.id 
    WHERE date>='$twoweeks' 
    ORDER BY voting.vote DESC 
    LIMIT 4
) t
ORDER BY entries.id; 
-- Or ORDER BY entries.published date;
```

Comment: I tried that and still get no results from the query. Any other idea? Thanks      `mysql_query("SELECT * FROM (SELECT entries.permalink, entries.title, voting.vote FROM entries LEFT JOIN voting ON voting.id = entries.id WHERE entries.category LIKE '%For Sale%' AND date>='$twoweeks' ORDER BY voting.vote DESC LIMIT 4) t ORDER BY entries.id");`

Comment: I actually found the probably on why everything wasn't working.  I needed to also query for my id number in my inner SELECT to use in the outer ORDER BY.  Essentially, I just needed to add entries.id in the inner select.